# Firebase java: during transaction errors, should I return Transaction.abort() vs Transaction.success(...)?

Tags: java, transactions, firebase

*Short version*:
In a Firebase transaction (in Java), if I get unexpected or inconsistent (stale) values from `MutableData.getValue()`, how should I error check and make sure that the transaction runs repeatedly if necessary? When do I use `Transaction.abort()` vs `Transaction.success()`?

*Long version*:
I wanted to write a Firebase transaction in Java that

1. checks if the value "foo" is stored at a location, logging errors if it's different or missing, and then
2. updates the value to "bar".

We expect "foo" to be at the location because it's successfully written by the same client before the transaction is run.

Consider the following:

```
public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData data) {
    String value = (String) data.getValue();
    if(value == null || !Transaction.equals("foo")) {
        return Transaction.abort();
    }
    data.setValue("bar");
    return Transaction.success(data);
}
```

I know `data.getValue()` may return stale values (including `null`) because of the eventual consistency of Firebase, and so the transaction may need to execute multiple times. But it seems like the transaction only ever runs once if I return `Transaction.abort()` in the `if` statement. If I replaced it with `Transaction.success(data)`, wouldn't I be committing bad values? How do I detect when the value is actually null or not "foo"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Self answer; correct if necessary!)

Through experimenting, I've found that I need to use `Transaction.success(...)` if I want the transaction to ever run again. `Transaction.abort()` always stops Firebase from trying again, so I should only use it when I'm sure that the transaction cannot proceed. (e.g. if `data.getValue()` indicates that something is off at the data location, and it will not be corrected by any pending writes.) In my example, `data.getValue() == null` seems like a particularly bad case to `abort()`, since there may be new values pending from the earlier write.

If I return `Transaction.success(data)` in the error cases, Firebase will make sure the consistency eventually works out. e.g. I will not accidentally end up writing `null` to that location, unless the value given by `data.getValue()` really is missing.

I can do all the error checking in the `Transaction.Handler.onComplete(...)` method, which has a `DataSnapshot` parameter to check the final data at the location.

Comment: This looks mostly correct. Transaction.abort() should be used when the set operation is no longer applicable (i.e. some value in the data has changed in a manner that the update is no longer appropriate). In all other cases, .success() is the appropriate choice. As you've discovered, onComplete() is the right place for doing all the success work that should run exactly once.

Comment: @Kato Is there anything in particular that's wrong, or just phrasing or something? (Just trying to learn more : ] )